# How to reach List<> fields in other class

Tags: c#, oop, visual-studio-2012

Hy, I'm stuck a bit. I'm trying to reach List's fields in other class. Here is my code example:

**Loader class:**

```
public List<Contact> LoadLicenses()
    {
        var listOfClients = new List<Contact>();     

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString =
                ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ContactManagerContext"].ConnectionString.ToString();
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Contacts]";
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var licenses = new Contact();

                        licenses.ContactId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ContactId"]);
                        licenses.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                        licenses.Address = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Address"]);
                        licenses.Email = reader["Email"].ToString();
                            listOfClients.Add(licenses);
                    }       
                }       
            }
        }
        return listOfClients;
    }
```

**ClientDuration class:**

```
public List<Contact> DurationLeft(/*DateTime _date*/)
    {
        Loader loader = new Loader();
        List<Contact> clientContacts = new List<Contact>();




         return clientContacts;
    }
```

In `ClientDuration` class I would like to do something like to reach fields (Email, Address,...) from List witch was declared in Loader class. I call `LoadLicenses` in `DurationLeft` method and then assign it to new List with same type as it was in Loader class. But then I can't reach fields.
How to do it? Please help!

Comment: how did you tried accessing the fields?

Comment: have you tried something like `clientContacts[0].Name`?

Comment: I tried like this: ClientContacts = loader.LoadLicenses();
ClientContacts. (nothing happens)...

Comment: You wrote 'I call LoadLicenses in DurationLeft' but it's not in your example. Where do you call `loader.LoadLicenses();`?

Comment: From other class you should [not access fields](http://stackoverflow.com/q/295104/1997232), but properties. You can expose list as [read only](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **try this**

```
public List<Contact> DurationLeft(/*DateTime _date*/)
 {
        Loader loader = new Loader();
        List<Contact> clientContacts = new List<Contact>();
         clientContacts =loader.LoadLicenses();
         var firstemailfield=clientContacts[0].Email;


         return clientContacts;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a collection of `Contacts` you must single out one contact before you access the properties/fields of it

I.e.

```
foreach(Contact contact in clientContacts)
 {
        Console.WriteLine(contact.name):
}
```

Or

```
clientContacts[0].name // access first contact in list
```